# Prove that if matrix $C = I - 2M $ and $M = M^2, $ then $ C^3 = C.$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm faced with a problem for which I haven't been given a correction, so I expected you could tell me if I am right or not, and in the later case give me the appropriate answer.

Let $M$ be an idempotent matrix such that $M=M^2$, and let $C = I - 2M$, with $I$ being the identity matrix.

**Prove that $C^3 = C$**

My answer:

$$C=I-2M$$
$$\Rightarrow C^2=(I-2M)^2$$
$$=I^2-4IM+4M^2$$
$$=I^2-4M^2+4M^2$$
$$=I$$
$$\Rightarrow C^3 = IC=C$$

Thank you.

Comment: In my opinion the idea of your proof is correct. However, you can't use the symbol $\iff$. Note that $C=I-2M$ is not equivalent to $C^2=I$. If you use $\implies$ it is correct. The same happens in $C^2=I\iff C^3=C.$

Comment: I agree with the above.  Also, to be clear, it might be helpful to write $C^3=C^2C=IC=C$

Comment: I changed the implication according to your correction. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe it's worth noting that $(I-2M)^2 = I^2-2IM-2MI+4M^2$ and $IM=MI=M$.